# running batch file, getting error and process output into a text file

Tags: c#, wpf

hi for the following code, why is it that i am getting this output in the error text file?

"'ha57061' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

my user name is cha57061. why am i missing the "c" and " ' "? please correct me if my code is wrong.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process runantc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            runantc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Documents and Settings/Cha57061/Desktop/New Folder/WPF/WpfApplication1/WpfApplication1/cmd.exe";
            runantc.StartInfo.Arguments = "antc.bat";
            runantc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            runantc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            runantc.Start();

            string procOutput = runantc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string procError = runantc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();



            TextWriter outputlog = new StreamWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/Cha57061/Desktop/New Folder/WPF/WpfApplication1/WpfApplication1/processoutput.txt");
            outputlog.Write(procOutput);
            outputlog.Close();


            TextWriter outputerror = new StreamWriter("C:/Documents and Settings/Cha57061/Desktop/New Folder/WPF/WpfApplication1/WpfApplication1/error.txt");
            outputerror.Write(procError);
            outputerror.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it solves your problem, but this is the first time i'm seeing file paths in C#.NET using forward slashes (/), not sure if they get converted to (\) automatically.
You might try rewriting your paths as indicated below

```
"C:\\Directory\\File" //the double slash is necessary since (\) indicates an escape character is to come)
@"C:\Directory\" // the @ modifier changes the default behavior and escape characters are not considered the same way
```

\c is a escape character, as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Never mind my answer, I see you're getting the batch file to execute correctly since you're getting output in the error text file. So SLaks is correct, your batch file has an error

Comment: it solves my problem. im interested in getting the output for now only. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's the wrong way to run a batch file.
You should set `FileName` directly to the path to your `.bat` file.

To answer your question, your batch file has a problem.